# Office Script Excel Pivot Table Count Instead of Sum

Tags: excel, office365, office-automation, office-scripts

I'm using Office Script to generate a pivot table and that works. However, for my data hierarchy, I need "count" instead of the default "sum". How do I go about doing that?

I'm adding a hierarchy using the following - this works but summarizes by "sum"

```
pivotTable.addRowHierarchy(pivotTable.getHierarchy("Company"));
pivotTable.addDataHierarchy(pivotTable.getHierarchy("Unit ID"));
```

From the script [reference page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.aggregationfunction?view=office-scripts), I need to somehow embed the `count` function into the above snippet. Does anyone know how to do that? I tried "Record Actions", but it wasn't able to catch the switch from "sum" to "count".

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - to change the summarize function, we need to chain the aggregate function to the end of `addDataHierarchy`.

The second line in the previous example therefore becomes:

```
pivotTable.addDataHierarchy(pivotTable.getHierarchy("Unit ID")).setSummarizeBy(ExcelScript.AggregationFunction.count);
```

For more details refer to [setSummarizeBy(summarizeBy)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.datapivothierarchy?view=office-scripts#setSummarizeBy_summarizeBy_).